# How to show that Hardy-Littlewood maximal function is lower semicontinous

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

I'm trying to show this by the absurd. If it's not, then, for every neighborhood of a given point $x$, exists a point $y$ such that $M(f)(y) > M(f)(x) + \epsilon$ so if I take a cube $Q_x$ such that $\frac{1}{|Q_x|}\int_{Q_x}|f(t)|dt$ is close to $M(f)(x)$ so the cube $Q_y$ that I take to approximate $M(f)(y)$ can't have the point $x$, but I don't know what to do if $Q_y$ is small enough to not have $x$. Also, I think the approach may not be good since analyzing points when I am talking about things with measure seems like a bad idea

Thanks

Comment: If your function $f$ is in the space of locally integrable fuunctions, $L^1_{loc}$ then $M(f)$ will be lower-semicontinuous.

Comment: I forgot to add that hypotesis. Could you help me understand why? Thanks

Comment: Local integrability is necessary otherwise  $Mf$ may not even be defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $\lambda>0.$ Let $E(\lambda) = \{x\in \mathbb R^n: Mf(x) > \lambda\}.$  You want to show that $E(\lambda)$ is open. So fix $x\in E(\lambda)$ and find an open cube $Q\ni x$ such that $\frac{1}{m(Q)}\int_{Q}|f(t)dt>\lambda.$ Now just observe that if $y\in Q,$ then by definition of the maximal function, $Mf(y)>\frac{1}{m(Q)}\int_{Q}|f(t)dt>\lambda$ so $Q\subseteq E(\lambda).$

Remark: I am using the definition of $Mf$ and follows:

for $f\in L_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb R^n),\ Mf(x)=\sup\{\frac{1}{m(Q)}\int_Q|f(t)|dt:\ Q\ \text{is a cube and}\ x\in Q\}.$ There is another common definition, namely,

$\tilde Mf(x)=\sup\{\frac{1}{m(Q)}\int_Q|f(t)|dt:\ Q\ \text{is a cube centered at}\ x\}.$

These two definitions are equivalent because it easy to show that

$\tilde Mf(x) ≤ Mf(x) ≤ 2^n\tilde Mf(x).$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have some place where I can read why that definition that $E(\lambda)$ is open means that $Mf$ is lower semicontinous? I had the definition that the function is either continous at that point or that the function takes lower values in a neighborhood

Comment: [This](https://cpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/sites.wustl.edu/dist/3/2139/files/2019/09/semi-continuity.pdf) might help.